# Image [caption] meta data does not render when inserting an image using a second WordPress content editor (wysiwyg)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have deployed some code into functions.php that gives me a second CLASSIC WYSIWYG / text editor (not dealing with Gutenberg right now) so that I can populate content for each post from both editors. Whenever I am editing a post, I see two wizzy's (the second editor is displayed in the admin area using a meta_box).

Having a second editor allows me to insert other code (like ads and other things) in between where each editor outputs to the page.

All works great except that when I insert images into the second editor, the caption data is escaped rather than rendered as the friendly caption text.

Below is the code for the second editor in functions.php.

```
     function custom_editor2_meta_box() {    
               add_meta_box ( 
                  'custom-editor2', 
                  __('Second Content Area', 'custom-editor2') , 
                  'custom_editor2',
                  'post'
               );

     }

     //Displaying the meta box
     function custom_editor2($post) {          
              echo "<h3>Second content area that appears after the inline advertisement.</h3>";
              $content = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_editor2', true);

              //This function adds the WYSIWYG Editor 
              wp_editor ( 
                $content , 
                'custom_editor2', 
                array ( "media_buttons" => true ) 
              );

     }

     //This function saves the data you put in the meta box
     function custom_editor2_save_postdata($post_id) {


        if( isset( $_POST['custom_editor_nonce'] ) && isset( $_POST['second'] ) ) {

            //Not save if the user hasn't submitted changes
            if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return;
            } 

            // Verifying whether input is coming from the proper form
            if ( ! wp_verify_nonce ( $_POST['custom_editor_nonce'] ) ) {
            return;
            } 

            // Making sure the user has permission
            if( 'post' == $_POST['second'] ) {
                   if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                        return;
                   }
            } 
        } 

        if (!empty($_POST['custom_editor2'])) {

            $data = $_POST['custom_editor2'];
            if (strlen($data) > 0) { update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_editor2', $data); }

        }

     }

    add_action('save_post', 'custom_editor2_save_postdata'); 
    add_action('admin_init', 'custom_editor2_meta_box');
```

What I expect to see is the image rendered and then the friendly text below it. Instead I see the [caption] syntax itself before and after the properly rendered image, as if the syntax was completely ignored by WordPress:

[caption id="attachment_165" align="alignnone" width="900"]

(Image is rendered properly because this is where the image tag is located within the caption syntax)

Friendly caption text is here[/caption]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the caption shortcode to be processed in the WYSIWYG editor? This is not the intended function inside the WYSIWYG, which is meant to show the raw shortcode. If it's not displaying correctly on the frontend (template) try wrapping your call to print the content of the editor in `do_shortcode`.

You *could* possibly try outputting your content into the editor using do_shortcode but that would only work once. I.e. once the shortcode is converted to HTML you'll have HTML floating around in your editor.

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what I needed, thank you a bunch.

`<?php echo do_shortcode( wpautop($content2)); ?>`